# Multiply values from two data frames based on shared identifier

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames:

Number 1:

```
>df1

 ID NUM QUANT STR IDENT
  1  30    30  10  1111
  1  30    50 100  2222
  2  60    60  20  1111
  3  15    15  10  3333
  3  20    10  10  1111
  4  60    30  20  2222
  5  30    20  15  3333
  6  45    60  10  2222
```

Number 2:

```
>df2

 IDENT FACTOR
  1111    1.0
  2222    0.5
  3333    2.0
```

I want to calculate a new value based on values in two data frames and append the calculated value to a new column called `RESULT` in data frame 1. The shared identifier in both data frames is `IDENT`.

The formula used to calculate the value:

```
STR*QUANT/NUM*FACTOR=RESULT
```

The final data frame should look like this:

```
  ID NUM QUANT STR IDENT RESULT
  1  30    30  10  1111  10.0000
  1  30    50 100  2222  83.3333
  2  60    60  20  1111  20.0000
  3  15    15  10  3333  20.0000
  3  20    10  10  1111   5.0000
  4  60    30  20  2222   5.0000
  5  30    20  15  3333  20.0000
  6  45    60  10  2222   6.6667
```

This is the code for reproducing the data frames:

```
ID = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6) 
NUM = c(30, 30, 60, 15, 20, 60, 30, 45) 
QUANT = c(30, 50, 60, 15, 10, 30, 20, 60) 
STR = c(10,100,20,10,10,20,15,10)
IDENT = c(1111,2222,1111,3333,1111,2222,3333,2222)
df1 = data.frame(ID, NUM, QUANT, STR, IDENT)   

IDENT = c(1111, 2222, 3333)
FACTOR = c(1, 0.5, 2)
df2 = data.frame(IDENT, FACTOR)

IDENT = c(1111,2222,1111,3333,1111,2222,3333,2222)
RESULT = c(10,83.3333,20,20,5,5,20,6.6667)
df3 = data.frame(ID, NUM, QUANT, STR, IDENT, RESULT)
```

Comment: `within(merge(df1, df2), { RESULT = STR*QUANT/NUM*FACTOR })`?

Comment: Or use `data.table` `setDT(df1)[df2, RESULT := STR*QUANT/NUM*FACTOR, on = .(IDENT)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A base R solution. We can merge the tow data frame first, calculate the result, and then finalize the output.

```
df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by = "IDENT", all.x = TRUE)
df3$RESULT <- with(df3, STR * QUANT / NUM * FACTOR)
df3 <- df3[, c("ID", "NUM", "QUANT", "STR", "IDENT", "RESULT")]
df3 <- df3[order(df3$ID, df3$NUM), ]
df3
#   ID NUM QUANT STR IDENT    RESULT
# 1  1  30    30  10  1111 10.000000
# 4  1  30    50 100  2222 83.333333
# 2  2  60    60  20  1111 20.000000
# 7  3  15    15  10  3333 20.000000
# 3  3  20    10  10  1111  5.000000
# 5  4  60    30  20  2222  5.000000
# 8  5  30    20  15  3333 20.000000
# 6  6  45    60  10  2222  6.666667
```

Or a `dplyr` solution with the same logic.

```
library(dplyr)

df3 <- df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by = "IDENT") %>%
  mutate(RESULT = STR * QUANT / NUM * FACTOR) %>%
  select(-FACTOR) %>%
  arrange(ID, NUM)
df3
#   ID NUM QUANT STR IDENT    RESULT
# 1  1  30    30  10  1111 10.000000
# 4  1  30    50 100  2222 83.333333
# 2  2  60    60  20  1111 20.000000
# 7  3  15    15  10  3333 20.000000
# 3  3  20    10  10  1111  5.000000
# 5  4  60    30  20  2222  5.000000
# 8  5  30    20  15  3333 20.000000
# 6  6  45    60  10  2222  6.666667
```

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by the comment by @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 above:

```
output <- within(merge(df1, df2), { RESULT = STR*QUANT/NUM*FACTOR })
output <- output[, !(names(output) %in% c("FACTOR"))]
output
```

### Demo

Comment: You can just remove the "FACTOR" column within `within` by adding `; rm(FACTOR)` in there, so the whole thing becomes `within(merge(df1, df2), { RESULT = STR*QUANT/NUM*FACTOR; rm(FACTOR) })`.

Answer (score 2):

We can also do a join with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2, RESULT := STR*QUANT/NUM*FACTOR, on = .(IDENT)]
df1
#   ID NUM QUANT STR IDENT    RESULT
#1:  1  30    30  10  1111 10.000000
#2:  1  30    50 100  2222 83.333333
#3:  2  60    60  20  1111 20.000000
#4:  3  15    15  10  3333 20.000000
#5:  3  20    10  10  1111  5.000000
#6:  4  60    30  20  2222  5.000000
#7:  5  30    20  15  3333 20.000000
#8:  6  45    60  10  2222  6.666667
```